# SQL query for referring another column in same table

Tags: mysql

This is my table:

[image: this is my table]

Now I need a query to return `name` as `student name` and `teacher_id` as `teacher name` by referring to the same table like below:

[image: I need result like this]

Comment: Read about [`SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) and [`JOIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html).

Comment: where the teacher name stored? in another table?

Comment: @shushu304 say goodnight Gracie

Comment: @shushu304 No there is only one table. teacher_name should come from teacher_id(f.k) by referring id(p.k)

Comment: i find the answer for this

Comment: with the help of self join

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a self-join on this table, like this:

```
select t1.name as student_name
     , t2.name as teacher_name
  from table_name t1 
  join table_name t2 
    on t1.teacher_id = t2.id;
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look in [Adjacency model](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) for query examples.